# Autotest Failing To Test for Integration Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, autotest

I am going through Hartl's RoR tutorial and am now in the section for integration testing.  As instructed I modified .autotest with:

```
require 'autotest/growl'
require 'autotest/fsevent'
require "autotest/restart" 

Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |autotest|
  autotest.add_mapping(/^spec\/requests\/.*_spec\.rb$/) do
    autotest.files_matching(/^spec\/requests\/.*_spec\.rb$/)
  end  
end
```

My set-up:

```
Z-Kidds-MacBook-Air:sample_app zkidd$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
Z-Kidds-MacBook-Air:sample_app zkidd$ rails -v
Rails 3.1.3
```

My error read out is this:

```
/Users/zkidd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -rrubygems -S /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/bin/rspec --tty '/Users/zkidd/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb' '/Users/zkidd/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb'
Exception encountered: #<SyntaxError: /Users/zkidd/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
    response.should have_selector('title,' :content => 'Home')
                                            ^
/Users/zkidd/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end>
backtrace: . . . .
```

I see that the error has that little carrot under the :content saying that autotest is expecting ")" instead of a colon.  But the tutorial specifics exactly what I wrote.  Here is the layout_links_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "LayoutLinks" do

  it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
    get '/'
    response.should have_selector('title,' :content => 'Home')
  end

  it "should have a Contact page at '/contact'" do
      get '/contact'
      response.should have_selector('title,' :content => "Contact")
    end

  it "should have an About page at '/about'" do
    get '/contact'
    response.should have_selector('title,' :content => "About")
  end

  it "should have a Help page at '/help'" do
    get '/help'
    response.should have_selector('/title' :content => "Help")
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted, all the lines like

```
response.should have_selector('title,' :content => 'Home')
```

should be

```
response.should have_selector('title', :content => 'Home')
```

*(the comma is outside the String)*.

For the last test, it's also `'title'` instead of `'/title'`